# ReactJS Routing Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently using ReactJS to construct a small web app.  I have the following parent function:

```
    const Main = () => {
        return (
            <div className="dialog-base">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/login/forgot_password" component={ForgotPwd}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/login/reset_password/:key" component={ResetPwd}></Route>
                        <Route exact path="/portal" component={Portal}></Route>
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
     }
```

and the following is the "Portal" component:

```
class Portal extends React.Component {
    render = () => {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter basename="/main">
                 <div className="navmenu">
                     <NavLink to="messaging" activeClassName="selected">Messaging</NavLink>
                     <NavLink to="files" activeClassName="selected"></NavLink>
                     <NavLink to="payledger" activeClassName="selected"></NavLink>
                 </div>
                 <div className="apparea">
                     <Switch>
                         <Route path="/messaging" component={Messaging}></Route>
                         <Route path="/files" component={Files}></Route>
                         <Route path="/payledger" component={PayLedger}></Route>
                     </Switch>
                 </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

When the portal component is loaded and I refresh the web page, the page goes blank.  I am assuming that this has something to do with the nested routing? Any help on how to fix it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two `<BrowserRouter />`. Just define one `<BrowserRouter />` in your top level component.
In react-router-dom v4+ the `<Route />` is just like a regular component and you can use it inside your components to render UI when the path matches the URL.

Here is the working codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-blackburn-l9dn6).
Make sure not to put `exact` on your parent `<Route />` because when you have child routes like `/main/messaging` the `<Route exact path="/main" />` never gets to render and therefore children of that route can't be rendered also.

You keep your `<Main />` component as is but remove the `exact` from the `<Route path='/portal' />` and change the `<Portal />`.

```
class Portal extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
      return (
         <React.Fragment>
             <div className="navmenu">
                 <NavLink to="/portal/messaging" activeClassName="selected">Messaging</NavLink>
                 <NavLink to="/portal/files" activeClassName="selected"></NavLink>
                 <NavLink to="/portal/payledger" activeClassName="selected"></NavLink>
             </div>
             <div className="apparea">
                 <Switch>
                     <Route path="/portal/messaging" component={Messaging}></Route>
                     <Route path="/portal/files" component={Files}></Route>
                     <Route path="/portal/payledger" component={PayLedger}></Route>
                 </Switch>
             </div>
          </React.Fragment>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Removing the `<BrowserRouter>` from the Portal component does not render the component in the `apparea` div.

Comment: Did you also include the `/main` in your routes since you removed the `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: I did.  The Portal component renders fine but clicking on one of the NavLinks makes the page go blank.

Comment: To speed up the process, I've added a code example in my answer. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is exactly how I have it set up.  I am importing the Messaging component as my test but when I click the Nav Link - the page returns blank

Comment: By the way, I replaced `<BrowserRouter>` with `<React.Fragment>` in the portal component.

Comment: Only issue with `/portal/messaging`, or with every route?

Comment: All of them :-(

Comment: @Elcid_91 Your switch on Portal, hae you tried omitting the '/portal` part of the paths, since the parent switch handles that?  I usually avoid nested routers myself.

Comment: I tried that as well and still get a blank page.  I appreciate your help by the way.  Thanks for your patience

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-sun-2cexb?file=/src/App.js

Comment: in the sandbox address bar make sure you put the "main" after the app

Comment: I have added a working codesandbox version and edited my answer.